# willdcard wxfiledialog

Tags: wxpython

I'm using a wxFileDialog to let the user pick a file. I've set a wildcard so that the user only can pick ".hed" files, which are headerfiles for my project, ".hed" files can be used for different datafiles and one ".hed" file can be headerfile for several datafiles. The filedialog should only allow one type of datafile.

A example, if I have the files test1.hed, test2.hed, test1.ab1, test1.ab2, test2.ab2. I only want the datafile of type "ab1" the dialog should only view test1.hed.

I know that the easy solution is to set a wildcard for "ab1" and the let the user pick, test1.ab1, but to make it more user friendly I would like to know if the other solution is possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the wildcard parameter to only use one type. I have an example in the following tutorial:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/

In that tutorial, I set the wildcard parameter to the following:

```
wildcard = "Python source (*.py)|*.py|" \
        "All files (*.*)|*.*"
```

This allows the user to select only Python files or they can change the drop-down to include all files. I think you could just change it to

```
wildcard = "Python source (*.py)|*.py"
```

and that would limit it to just Python files. In your case, you would want something like

```
wildcard = "Header files (*.hed)|*.hed"
```

Comment: I already use wildcard so that the dialog only show .hed files, but I want to filter it more, so that it only show the .hed file which has a correspondent datafile of the right type

Comment: Yeah, so in your example, you'd only have the last line instead of having two lines.